# Finding CPU Platform Name and Family

Tags: vb.net, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpuid

I’ve been Googling all morning trying to find a way to use VB.Net code to find the platform and family of my CPU.

For instance: 
**Intel Xeon (*Haswell*)** OR **Intel Xeon (*Sandy Bridge*)**

I have a program I’ve been working on that has several different versions *specifically optimized* for certain *CPU platforms/families/generations.*

So it’s important that my software is able to find the *CPU platform/family/generation* (i.e. **Haswell/Broadwell/Ivy Bridge/Sandy Bridge/Coffee Lake...**) so that it can run the version optimized for that CPU.

Everything I found so far can give me EVERY bit of info about my CPU and/or system **EXCEPT** the *CPU platform/family/generation.*

Can any of you guys help me out with this, or provide some kind of workaround to help?

Comment: [System.Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(v=vs.110).aspx) should help

Comment: I feel like you may have misunderstood what I’m looking for... I’ve been through those. They don’t provide the CPU platform. I need a way to know what the CPU platform is (Haswell, Sandy Bridge, etc...). System.Management and your link, Stephen, do not provide the information I need. So this isn’t a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: Add a dictionary with these values https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html The generation # is the first integer after the model (`i7-7500` is 7th gen as the 7 is the integer after the dash)

Comment: If you are implementing a CPU dispatcher (a code that dispatches to optimized routines based on the CPU version) then you should *avoid* the marketing/internal names like Haswell & C. Intel and AMD gave you the family, the model and the stepping numbers exactly for this purpose. The same brand name can include slightly different microarchitecture. Use the F/M/S numbers. You can use the `cpuid` instruction, I'm sure there are hundreds of libraries in .NET for this.

Comment: Oooh, good one, Jacob. It may work. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Margaret. I appreciate your insight, and this sounds perfect.